# Uncheck checkbox when another is checked

Tags: wpf, checkbox

I have two `checkboxes`. When I check one, I want the other to uncheck if it's currently checked. Both can be unchecked. Currently, I can check one, but when I check the other, both of them uncheck. I'm having trouble figuring out why.

Note: I want to do this all in the .xaml if possible. I've been messing with data triggers to get the proper effect with no luck so far.

```
<CheckBox Name="SYOChkBox">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=UTMChkBox}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                            Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Name="UTMChkBox">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SYOChkBox}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                            Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Do you need it to be possible for both of them to be unchecked at once? You should really be doing this logic in the viewmodel properties they respective `CheckBox.IsChecked` properties are bound to (and if you don't have a viewmodel, you should).

Comment: Yes, need both of them to be able to be unchecked. I do have a viewmodel, thought I was just missing something simple to be able to do this xaml only though! But if the only way is to use properties in the viewmodel, I can do that.

Comment: I've fiddled with it a bit and I don't think pure XAML is smart enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ***really*** be using a `ViewModel` to do this (I'll leave a snippet on how you could do it using a VM at the end of the post).

Anyway, here's what I was able to do with XAML only

## Using CheckBox

The problem with using this approach is that when both are checked, both of the triggers will be triggered (??), and both will be unchecked. So, I guess what you can do is this:

[image: Output]

`CheckBox X` will normally uncheck when you check `CheckBox Y`, but `CheckBox X` just won't check while `CheckBox Y` is checked.

```
    <CheckBox Name="SYOChkBox">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=UTMChkBox}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SYOChkBox}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Name="UTMChkBox" />
```

## Using RadioButton

I know it isn't what you asked, but as a sugestion, you could use a `RadioButton`, the code would be a lot cleaner:

[image: RadioButton alternative]

```
<RadioButton>Option A</RadioButton>
<RadioButton>Option B</RadioButton>
<RadioButton>None</RadioButton>
```

## Using `ViewModel`

#### XAML

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_CheckBoxA}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_CheckBoxB}" />
```

#### Code-behind:

```
private bool _IsChecked_CheckBoxA;
private bool _IsChecked_CheckBoxB;

public bool IsChecked_CheckBoxA
{
    get
    {
        return _IsChecked_CheckBoxA;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value)
            IsChecked_CheckBoxB = false;

        _IsChecked_CheckBoxA = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public bool IsChecked_CheckBoxB
{
    get
    {
        return _IsChecked_CheckBoxB;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value)
            IsChecked_CheckBoxA = false;

        _IsChecked_CheckBoxB = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it might not be doable in just xaml, and using a viewmodel is suggested. So here's what I have that works:

Xaml:

```
<CheckBox Name="SYOChkBox"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedSYO}" />
<CheckBox Name="UTMChkBox"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedUTM}" />
```

Viewmodel:

```
private bool _isCheckedSYO;
public bool IsCheckedSYO
{
    get { return _isCheckedSYO; }
    set 
    {
        if (true == value) //if checked
        {
            IsCheckedUTM = false; //uncheck the UTM check box
            _isCheckedSYO = value;
        }
        else
        {
            _isCheckedSYO = value;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckedSYO");
    }
}

private bool _isCheckedUTM;
public bool IsCheckedUTM
{
    get { return _isCheckedUTM; }
    set
    {
        if (true == value) //if checked
        {
            IsCheckedSYO = false; //uncheck the SYO checkbox
            _isCheckedUTM = value;
        }
        else
        {
            _isCheckedUTM = value;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckedUTM");
    }
}
```